# GoColly set proxy for every request

Tags: go

I started to deal with Colly.
I am trying to set a proxy for every request. But all requests do not go through a proxy

It should work
https://github.com/gocolly/colly/blob/master/request.go#L52

I have added this to my code. But requests go without a proxy as before

```
c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) { 
  r.ProxyURL = "..." 
}
```

Maybe I didn’t understand correctly how this should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `ProxyURL` in the callback function, have you tried setting it on the collector ?

```golang
// SetProxy sets a proxy for the collector. This method overrides the previously
// used http.Transport if the type of the transport is not http.RoundTripper.
// The proxy type is determined by the URL scheme. "http"
// and "socks5" are supported. If the scheme is empty,
// "http" is assumed.
func (c *Collector) SetProxy(proxyURL string) error {
    proxyParsed, err := url.Parse(proxyURL)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    c.SetProxyFunc(http.ProxyURL(proxyParsed))

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I would like to have more control than setting a single proxy for the whole collector. I tried to do as advised here https://github.com/gocolly/colly/issues/110

Comment: Please let us know if this worked. If it works I'd appreciate that you mark the answer as accepted. And if it didn't I should remove my post.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "more control", but you can set a function to decide how you want to set the proxy on a per request basis with `(c *Collector) SetProxyFunc(p ProxyFunc)`. It just relies on http.Transport.Proxy.

Comment: Well, my last comment is actually what is already suggested on your link, I should have read :)

Comment: It turns out that `Request.ProxyURL = .. ` does not establish a proxy for the request. And it makes it possible to find out through which proxy the request passed.

Comment: after using `c.SetProxyFunc (proxy.RoundRobinProxySwitcher (...))` Do proxies automatically change on every request?

Comment: I think `proxy.RoundRobinProxySwitcher` is just a way to load-balance on different proxies.